# four point in a row

Tags: pigeonhole-principle

We have painted all dots of page with two colors(blue and green), proof that there are four point with green color in a line that distance of any two neighbors of this four is one unit **or** there are two blue dots with one unit distance.

other assumptions:

unit is a fixed length

Comment: A lot of information is needed to make this question understandable.  Is a "unit" a fixed length?  If so, how big is a page?  What points are colored -- all of them, or some lattice?  What constitutes "in a row" -- does that just mean collinear?

Comment: @mjqxxxx you was right! it was my mistake!:D